# Confusion with Java Time parsing UTC

Tags: java, parsing, datetime, java-time, localtime

I am confused with time handling in java time. I so long worked under the assumption that if a timestamp is specified as a zulu time, java would take care of the offset with regards to local time.

To illustrate. I am currently in BST which has an offset of UTC +1. With that in mind, I would expect this zulu time:

```
2016-09-12T13:15:17.309Z
```

to be

```
2016-09-12T14:15:17.309
```

LocalDateTime after parsing it. This is because my default systemtime is set to BST and the above timestamp (zulu time) specifies that it is a UTC time.

Instead however consider this sample:

```
        String ts = "2016-09-12T13:15:17.309Z";
        LocalDateTime parse = LocalDateTime.parse(ts, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME);
        System.out.println(parse);
```

This will print:

```
2016-09-12T13:15:17.309
```

So the timestamp, parsed as a LocalDateTime, is not recognised as UTC time and instead treated as localtime directly. 
So I thought, maybe I need to parse it as a ZonedDateTime and convert it to LocalDateTime specifically in order to get the correct local time. With this test:

```
        String ts = "2016-09-12T13:15:17.309Z";
        ZonedDateTime parse = ZonedDateTime.parse(ts, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME);
        System.out.println(parse);
        System.out.println(parse.toLocalDateTime());
```

I get the outputs:

```
2016-09-12T13:15:17.309Z
2016-09-12T13:15:17.309
```

Same output for both dates.

The only way to correctly parse this that I could find, is:

```
    String ts = "2016-09-12T13:15:17.309Z";
    Instant instant = Instant.parse(ts); // parses UTC
    LocalDateTime ofInstant = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.systemDefault());
    System.out.println(instant);
    System.out.println(ofInstant);
```

This prints:

```
2016-09-12T13:15:17.309Z
2016-09-12T14:15:17.309
```

Which is correct.

So the question(s) are:

- Shouldn't java time recognise a UTC timestamp and parse it to the correct system default?
- How can I use the `LocalDateTime#parse` approach to get the correct result?
- Should I use `Instant` for everything now and discard the parsing?

The issue is that `jersey/jackson`'s java time modules parse the timestamps using the ISO format and the regular `LocalDateTime#parse` methods. I realised that my times are no off since they are being treated as `LocalTime` while in fact they are in Zulu time.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the purpose of [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html).

To quote the class documentation:

> A date-time without a time-zone in the ISO-8601 calendar system, such as {@code 2007-12-03T10:15:30}.
>
> …
>
> This class does not store or represent a time-zone. Instead, it is a description of the date, as used for birthdays, combined with the local time as seen on a wall clock. It cannot represent an instant on the time-line without additional information such as an offset or time-zone.

So it's explicit purpose is just to represent a date and time *without* a time-zone. It's porpose is *not* to represent a date and time *in the local time zone*.

Therefore each conversion just strips the time zone.

So for your purposes you need a `ZonedDateTime` with `ZoneId.systemDefault()` as you already used in your third example.

For your second example this could be:

```
String ts = "2016-09-12T13:15:17.309Z";
ZonedDateTime parse = 
    ZonedDateTime.parse(ts, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME)
        .withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault());
System.out.println(parse);
System.out.println(parse.toLocalDateTime());
```

Comment: Your example looks like it would do the instant conversation of my example 3. You are right, I misunderstood what LocalDateTime stands for. ughh.. timezones :) Thanks

Comment: Ah, so ZonedDateTime recognises the timezone as "Z" which it interprets as UTC automatically (just what I want) - is that right?

Comment: @pandaadb Yeah, it's probably just another way for writing this.

Comment: @pandaadb Yes, it is recognized correctly by the parser. It's just that the conversion to `LocalDateTime` does strip it.

Answer (score 11):

## tl;dr

- Do ***not*** use [`LocalDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html).
- Use [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) & [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

Example:

```
Instant.parse( "2016-09-12T13:15:17.309Z" )
       .atZone( ZoneId.of( "Europe/London" ) )
       .toString();
```

> 2016-09-12T14:15:17.309+01:00[Europe/London]

[Run in IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/s75eux).

## Details

The [Answer by Krüske](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39451909/642706) is correct. You misunderstand the meaning of `LocalDateTime` class. It does *not* represent the date-time of a particular locality. Just the opposite, it does *not* represent an actual moment at all.

I suggest thinking of `Instant` as your basic building-block class in java.time. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

Your input string complies with the ISO 8601 format used by default in the `Instant` class for both parsing and generating string representations. The `Z` on the end is short for `Zulu` and means UTC. No need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2016-09-12T13:15:17.309Z" );
```

As a programmer you should learn to think and work in UTC primarily. Forget about your own time zone. Think of UTC as the One True Time. Apply a time zone as a variation, and only as needed.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `BST` or `EST` or `IST` as they are not true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!). If by `BST` you meant British Summer Time, then the actual time zone name would be [`Europe/London`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/London). The java.time classes will determine how to adjust for any anomalies including Daylight Saving Time (DST).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Europe/London" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts ***ThreeTen-Backport*** (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).