# How to LocalDateTime but use server time or internet time?

Tags: java, java-time, localtime, localdate

I have been using Java 11 `LocalDateTime` but realised that it uses the time of the system. Are there alternatives that allow me to use the system time of a server or web time in my country?

Edit: After trying Instant I am very close to result I am after.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.now(), ZoneId.of("Europe/London"));
```

The Time is now correct but the date is still picking the system date? If I change the date to Christmas and the timezone of my system to UTC +1 Amsterdam the time will be ZoneId.of("Europe/London") UTC 0 but the date still shows as christmas. Any ideas?

@Ole V.V. I do not believe this is a duplicate question? similar, yes! duplicate no? If you can link me to what you believe is a duplicate that would be great.

Comment: Pretty close to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442192/how-to-use-an-internet-time-server-to-get-the-time

Comment: I don't believe LocalDateTime uses the system's time (as in, it uses the "local" system time without any information). It simply represents time without any information of timezone etc. I have asked a related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39451432/confusion-with-java-time-parsing-utc

Comment: I just tested local date time and changed my system time it was getting that value and not the actual real date and time. I think the link from fabian has more or less helped me to work towards getting the results I want.

Comment: @pandaadb The asker probably means that `LocalDateTime.now()` uses the system clock to obtain the current time. If the system clock is wrong, you get the wrong time.

Comment: fair enough - i may have misunderstood this :)  In that case I'd recommend `Instant` and using a specific timezone instead